# List method in python returns empty list when we pass magic mock object

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a python code which needs to be run in both Python 2 and 3.
In python 2 `dict.values()` returns list but in python 3 it returns `dict_val` object. So to make it compatible I have put `list(dict.values())`. It works fine. But when I am doing a Unit test using python mock there is one error. I am mocking `dict.values()` and it gives output like this `<MagicMock name='mock().values()' id='1099587993168'>`, but when I use a list, it makes this empty list. Below is the example.

function file:

```
class abc():    
 def get_dict(self, key):#i want to mock this as its depends on other method also
    dic = {'key': {'smaplekey': 'samplevalue'}}# its sample - 
    return dic['key']

 def run_method(self, val):
    print val

 def a(self,key):
  print 'before list'
  print self.get_dict(key).values()
  print list(self.get_dict(key).values())
  b = list(self.get_dict(key).values())[0]
  print 'after list'
  self.run_method(b)
```

test file:

```
import unittest
from mock import Mock, patch, MagicMock, ANY
import function_file
class TestA(unittest.TestCase):
  @patch('function_file.abc.run_method')
  @patch('function_file.abc.get_dict',MagicMock(return_vlaue={'key': {}}))
  def test_a(self, mock_run_method):
    manager = function_file.abc()
    result = manager.a('key')
    mock_run_method.assert_called_once_with(ANY, create=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Here list method make magic mock object empty list so it is failing.
And below is the python error

```
 before list
<MagicMock name='mock().values()' id='1099803145040'>
[]
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_a (__main__.TestA)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1305, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "test_manager.py", line 9, in test_a
    result = manager.a('key')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/abcd/function_file.py", line 13, in a
    b = list(self.get_dict(key).values())[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.004s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Here it is going inside the 'a' method and printing also, but list method make mock object empty list. List method should not make mock object empty list

Comment: I have updated the whole code and results also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:

```
@patch('get_dict',MagicMock(return_vlaue={'key': {}}))
```

to

```
@patch('__main__.get_dict', MagicMock(return_value={'key': 1}))
```

patch target should in the form "module.object_name", you missed namespace, remain mistakes are typos.

Comment: @patch('module.get_dict',MagicMock(return_vlaue={'key': {}})) gives output <MagicMock name='mock().values()' id='1099587993168'>. here module i have used as sample. It is going inside 'a' method but it is failing at list(get_dict(key).values())[0], bcoz list makes mock object empty list.

Comment: Yes and its going inside ''a" method. Only list method is the problem. It makes magic mock object empty list.

Comment: cannot reproduce you *new* issue.

Comment: all your issue is a typo, i have voted to close this.

Comment: How can i fix the return value type? What should be  in the return value?

Comment: please fix the `return_vlaue` -> `return_value` typo.

Answer (score 0):

Try `@patch(__name__ + '.get_dict', MagicMock(return_value={'key': {})`
to give a proper target to your mock.

Comment: @patch('module.get_dict',MagicMock(return_vlaue={'key': {}})) gives output <MagicMock name='mock().values()' id='1099587993168'>. here module i have used as sample. It is going inside 'a' method but it is failing at list(get_dict(key).values())[0], bcoz list makes mock object empty list

Comment: Have you tried this kind of workaround. My version worked on both python versions?
  `@patch(__name__ + '.get_dict')
  def test_a_1(self, mock):
    mock.return_value = {'key': {}}
    result = a('key')
    self.assertEqual(result, 1)`

Comment: Let me try this